# Linking to Image file on another computer on same network

Tags: networking, hyperlink, file-sharing

Let's say I have my computer with IPAddress 192.168.50.50 and another computer on the same network with IPAddress 192.168.50.51.

If I save an image to my pc in the My Pictures folder (C:\Users\%UserName%\Pictures), is there a hyperlink I can use on the second PC to access this image? If so, what would the format of the hyperlink be?

I intend to use this to save images and send the hyperlink to other computers. I understand how I am going to send the image link over TCP-IP, I just need to understand how to make the hyperlink to the image on my local system so computers on network can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have to have a webserver host the files and there is no way around it incase anyone else has this problem.